# How to set the content size of NSScrollView?

Tags: macos, nsscrollview

I am new to Mac OSX Programming. I have created on iOS apps in which I can set The content size of UISCrollView by using contentSize property. But there is no such property I found for Mac Apps. How it can be done and how can I enable the scrolling in Mac App. I looked on to the other questions on Stackoverflow but I didn't find anything relevant.
Thanks-

Comment: Did you find anything on this?

Answer (score 31):

NSScrollView has documentView attached to it. You can change the content size by updating the frame of documentView.

`[scrollView.documentView setFrame: NSMakeRect(0,0,new_width, new_height) ];`

Comment: CGRectMake is incompatible with NSRect and does not compile.

Comment: It compiles just fine. NSRect is just a typedef of CGRect.

Comment: Only when compiling for 64-bit.

Comment: You may use NSMakeRect instead

Comment: NOTE: it's very important that you update the *frame* of the documentView, and not its bounds.  I just wasted a couple of days because I was changing the bounds, which produces a completely different result than the one intended.

Comment: Does not seem to work in Swift as documentView is a constant and its variables can therefore not be assigned to.